# Opening YouTube Player API in Modal Window

Tags: java, youtube, window, youtube-api, modal-dialog

I am building a site using the bootstrap framework and would like to allow a user to click a button that will open a youtube video inside of a modal window. I would like the player in the modal window to be a chromeless player that uses the youtube player api and I'll create all my own buttons like play, pause, stop etc. Using this code I can get the modal window to open and play the correct video once, but after closing the window and clicking another link to open a different video in the modal window, the 1st video loads everytime. How can I make it open and load different videos?

```
  <a class="btn btn-small btn-inverse" onClick="openPlayerLoadVideo('bR2bMFwU6sI');">Demo Video</a>
  <a class="btn btn-small btn-inverse" onClick="openPlayerLoadVideo('KqX-4aRC0K4');">Demo Video</a>

  function openPlayerLoadVideo(videoCode) {
    $('#demo_viewer').modal({show:true});
    var videoID = videoCode; 
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
                       "videoDiv", "590", "400", "9", null, null, params, atts);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a caching issue.  Try using the YouTube iframe embed, which is also the preferred way to embed videos.  Here's the blog post about it.
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

You can continue to construct the url as you are now or you can try using `loadVideoById` as detailed in the api.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference